# Geth stopped syncing after a while

Tags: go-ethereum

Running `geth` on clean `ubuntu 14.04 x64`

After running `geth --fast` syncing stoppes on some point, like that:

```
I0321 11:31:39.971284 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 188 txs in 3.539956421s. #178700 [f77611b1 / 81122e65]
I0321 11:31:46.274148 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 570 txs in 6.300590994s. #178956 [6dd11d8f / dba1d24d]
I0321 11:31:51.141699 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 252 txs in 4.864679475s. #179212 [bd22d2ba / 95e5cd8a]
I0321 11:32:07.463688 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 941 txs in 16.316555449s. #179468 [d8d6ad74 / 9d3820b7]
I0321 11:32:12.135834 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 256 txs in 4.66919216s. #179724 [c43d0171 / 3ce5ce4d]
I0321 11:32:17.759139 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 199 txs in 5.617463517s. #179980 [e4844648 / 602a284b]
I0321 11:32:24.569821 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 256 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 195 txs in 6.807623198s. #180236 [7b5c8d4b / 8e9051e3]
I0321 11:32:25.599760 core/blockchain.go:959] imported 60 block(s) (0 queued 0 ignored) including 45 txs in 1.029029976s. #180296 [ec5742fb / 7b71e76e]
```

It continue after `Ctrl+C` and run again. But what is the problem?

Comment: without `--fast` flag everything is fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at your logs, fast sync is disabled. Fast is only ever allowed if your database is empty and/or haven't imported any blocks yet, only did previous fast sync attempts.

Given this, it actually doesn't matter if you specify fast or not, your node does **not** do fast sync, since you started a slow sync at some point and inherently disabled fast sync for life. To re-enable fast sync you need to delete your `chaindata` folder and start sync from scratch.

I can't say for sure why sync might stall, but if it happens often/regularly/reproducably, please run geth with `--vmodule=downloader=6` (which will output a ton of logs as it syncs) and post the logs on [our issue tracker](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues) with all the logs in a [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/).

Comment: You are absolutely right. I start slow sync, but  switched to `--fast` after noticing how much time it wood take. I think this is common user case, so you should put some warning.

Comment: Geth 1.5 will probably switch over to a different model where we have `archive` nodes and `full` nodes. Archives would slow sync and retain state by default. Full ones would fast sync and prune state by default.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a coincidence, but running `geth` like this:

```
geth --rpc
```

fixed the problem for me. Found the solution using this guide:
https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/guides/how-to-mine-ethereum/

Comment: Just be careful about the use of `--rpc` that no one else has access to your computer - see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/how-to-reduce-the-chances-of-your-ethereum-wallet-getting-hacked .

Comment: `--rpc` has nothing to do with syncing.it's different module, different executable code. Your problem most like was a connection loss, or some other networking problem/. You restarted and it worked because of the restart.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick addition. I started the sync on slow, then used the fast command and didn't realize it had no effect.

I haven't managed to test the use of the blockchain yet, but I moved most of the files; starting with the earliest (say 70%) from the start of the appdata folder onto another hard drive.

This enabled me to start fast sync from where I left off (I wish I had done this from the start, it's taken 18 hours so far and would probably be finished by now!). Note though that my sync is also suffering from stalling.