# Can I access my account using some http request?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, accounts

I am accessing my accounts and everything using Ethereum Wallet (Mist) but I was wondering is there any possible way to access my account using some `http request`?

Comment: Yes, but if you're not careful and don't do it safely and correctly, that means anyone online could also access your account with an http request. See http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/how-to-reduce-the-chances-of-your-ethereum-wallet-getting-hacked

Comment: Even I got {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}} when I hit local host. Prashant, Did u find any method?

Comment: I have wrote a HTML script using web3, and I am able to access my accounts, contracts and everything that I could access from geth console.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, but you need to launch **geth** with the **web3** and **personal** modules:

```
geth --datadir myGethDirectory --rpc --rpcport "8000" --rpc-api "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,personal,web3"
```

Then you can either [throw](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) JSON objects at the loop back address on port 8000 or use [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) to interact with the client.

Note that anyone with access to the machine running **geth** will be able to use its RPC interface. So use this option only on trusted/secure networks.

For how to use **web3** see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2531/common-useful-javascript-snippets-for-geth) question and the [documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API).

To unlock an account run:

```
web3.personal.unlockAccount("0x1234...", "password", timeout);
```

Comment: Thanks. but I have never worked with web3, so any help on how to use web3 to make https request to my account?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for support but the link provided contains whole `web3` documentation. I specifically wanted to know **How** **can** **I** **access** **my** **accounts** **using** **http** **request**. Using `web3` is quite general answer .Do I need to ask separate question for this?

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: I am puzzled with this question. Probably I couldn't make myself clear enough in question. I have used `personal.unlockAccount(..)` to unlock and access my account from geth console. What if I want to access my account from a web browser.  If my rpcport is `xxxx` . Currently when I access `http://localhost:xxxx/` I get `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}`. I wish if i could get my any details regarding my account here.

Comment: You need to send valid JSON-RPC requests; in Javascript, the web3 library will do this for you. You can't simply load the RPC URL in your browser and expect to get a useful result.

Comment: Thanks for response. I know of course I need to send a valid JSON-RPC requests, but what will be format of that request? I asked separate question on that [What will be format of data to execute a function from Web](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8529/what-will-be-the-format-of-data-to-execute-a-function-from-web). You can post you valuable answer/comment there.