# What will be the format of data to execute a function from web

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment

I have deployed a cryptocurrent on Private testNet from [here](https://www.ethereum.org/token). I have deployed two contracts, lets call them contract1 and contract2. Contract1 has less features than contract2 (like transferFrom() functionality was removed). 
Now I am using

```
geth --identity "XXXX" --fast --cache=1024 --jitvm --rpc --rpcport "yyyy" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir "chaindata" --port "xxxx"  --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,admin,debug,miner,personal,web3" --autodag --networkid xxxx --nat "any" -ipcpath "/home/pr.singh/.ethereum/geth.ipc"  console
```

to connect to geth console. Now I want to execute `transfer()` function of `contract2`. I know how to do it from geth console  (using abi defination fo contract). But how to do it using web browser. What request do I need to send and HOW? 
When I hit url `http://localhost:yyyy/` (where yyyy is my rpcport) , I get `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}` as output, so I know my port is working fine.
 But in what format do I need to send data to this port. Like how will it know which method of which contract needs to be executed. Any tutorial avilable on that. TIA.

Comment: As you have labeled it correctly: use web3js in your webpage's javascript. As long as you are doing it locally it will be fine, for production use metamask or infura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to author a HTML interface which uses the web3js library.  For my own testing purposes, I simply drop the [web3.js library](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/tree/develop/lib) into the DAPP directory and import it in the HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="web3.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var Web3 = require('web3');
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
...
```

Contracts can be connected to by creating contract objects and assigning the object an address.

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,...}]);
var forInstance = contract.at("0xabcd...");
```

Then you can call or send to the contract and web3 functions as per normal...

```
var d = forInstance.getData();
forInstance.setData('foo', {from:eth.accounts[0]});
```

Comment: So, do you mean I need to write HTML code for that? I am not a UI developer and have no idea how to write HTML code to access on my contract. Does Ethereum not provide any way to access your accounts and contracts from a web browser. Once I deployed a contract using MIST, I want to access all its functions using web, but How to do that? I am really puzzled.

Comment: Accessing anything from a web browser implies that 'someone' has to write an HTML interface.  Mist itself allows for direct interaction with your contract more through 'watch contract'.  There are also plugins like MetaMask that allow Web3 enable pages to connect to a node, but still that requires some HTML authoring.  Keep in mind through that the Ethereum design philosophy has purposely been avoiding 'just another web page' mentality and that DAPP's a at their best when integrated with Mist itself.

Comment: Thanks buddy. Wrote HTML code for that, the same that wrote on geth console and now I am able to know balance and carry out transactions using  web.

Comment: I was trying to access the functions written on inside my code on `http:localhost:yyyy` where `yyyy` is the rpcport. But I get `error:32601`  and a message that function doesn't exist, but when I use commands listed [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getbalance) , I get expected output.Like when I use `curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":65}' http://localhost:8012/` I get list of accounts. I want to access my functions that I wrote using `web3.js` in similar manner, how can I do that? TIA

Comment: You might want to open a new question for that

Comment: I have opened a new question for that [Using my contract's functions via RPC calls](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8671/using-my-contracts-functions-via-rpc-calls). Please have a look. Thanks