# Using my contract's functions via RPC calls

Tags: contract-development, json-rpc

I have written a HTML interface which uses [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) library. For my testing, I dropped `web3.js` library into the CoinCode directory and import it in HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bignumber.js/bignumber.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="web3//dist/web3-light.js"></script>
    var Web3 = require('web3');
    var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8019"));
```

Then, I connected to my contract there by using:

```
var contract1=web3.eth.contract(abiDefination).at(address);
```

and I was able to use all the functions of my contract by:

```
contract1.transfer(..)
contract1.checkBalance("0x..")
contract1.sell(..)
```

But, how can I make `rpc` calls to my functions.
Like I can use following call to list accounts:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_accounts","params":[],"id":6‌​5}' http://localhost:8019/
```

Can I use functions of my contract in similar fashion, like:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"contract1_checkBalance","params":["0x.."],"id":6‌​5}' http://localhost:8019/
```

and get desired output. Currently when I use such post calls I get:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
    "id": 67
    "error": {
        "code": -32601
        "message": "The method contract1_checkBalance does not exist/is not available"
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently I am working on private TestNet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web3 will take care of the RPC calls, so to make a call without a transaction, for instance for `checkBalance()`, [you call it thus](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-methods):

```
// If `checkBalance` is `constant`:
var balance = contract1.checkBalance("0x..");
// otherwise
var balance = contract1.checkBalance.call("0x..");
```

To make a call with a transaction:

```
var txHash = contract1.transfer(param1, param2, { from: senderAccount });
// or
var txHash = contract1.transfer.sendTransaction(param1, param2, { from: senderAccount });
```

Edit:

On the other hand, if you want to make a straight URL call, you need to prepare the data to send with:

```
var callData = contract1.checkBalance.getData("0x..");
```

Then your `curl` call [looks like](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_call):

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_call","params":[{"to": contractAddress, "data": callData}],"id":6‌​5}' http://localhost:8019/
```

And if you want to send a transaction to your contract, similarly:

```
var callData = contract1.transfer.getData(param1, param2);
```

Then you `curl` call [looks like](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendtransaction):

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{"from": account, "to": contractAddress, "data": callData}],"id":6‌​5}' http://localhost:8019/
```

After you have looked at how data is packaged in this `callData`, you should be able to assemble it without even the help of `contract1`.

Comment: Probably you got me wrong,or I was unclear with my question. I am able to call all my functions like `transfer(..)`, as you are saying, in a JS code. But, i want to know how can I access my functions on `localhost:8019/`. Currently, I have written code for a HTML page which I rum by double-clicking it. I want to access it on a url like `localhost:8019`. How can I do that? I have given scenarios like I am able to access `eth_accounts` method there, but is there anyway I can post a request on `localhost:8019` with function name like `contract1.checkBalance` instead of `eth_accounts`.

Comment: I updated the answer with further examples.

Comment: sorry but I did't get desired output, when I used, `curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_sendTransaction","params":[{from: "0x1c2DDB63F2084B70a27Ec7da01126dadbE084945", to: "0xcEEFFdd02D22b315ACa57D0180F99C0e5BDA5255", data: contract1.transfer.getData("0x936335307DEfa5a611a00eb0775F176469d5D288", 1100)}],"id":65}' http://localhost:8019` I got `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"invalid character 'f' looking for beginning of object key string"}}` as response.

Comment: Sorry: must be `{"from":...`

Comment: This also didn't work. I even tried using `sendTransaction` to carry transactions of contract drom geth by, `callData=contract1.transfer.getData(param1.param2)` and then executing, `eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], data: callData})`. When I debugged the transaction, I got `Invalid opcode 4d697373696e67206f70636f64652030786139`.

Comment: Did you omit the `to: contractAddress` field? If you omit it, the `data:` field is understood as a contract deployment...

Comment: Note that you may have to add a block parameter to `eth_call` - see http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/9349/1268.