# Use of RPC, IPC and ws in go-ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, rpc, ipc

RPC provides http-rpc server.But what is the use of  IPC and ws?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look the answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/10682
Understanding of websockets can also help https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket