# GETH node works on Apache but not on ExpressJs

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs, linux

I had a running GETH node linked to my localhost (hosted with Apache) , I had to migrate the project on a ExpressJs running on port 3000 and now I have

```
Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node http://localhost:8545
```

When I run the exact same code with the same GETH instance (but with Xampp) , everything works fine.

Any clue ? Thanks all

EDIT :

Apparently , it's maybe because NodeJS doesn't have the writing permission. Does anyone knows how to allow it on Linux ? Thanks

Comment: Any interest in trying to connect via IPC pipe? Some of the details are explained in [this answer and its comments](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/16167/9677).