# Is it possible to hack an ethereum account?

Tags: accounts, security, ethereum-wallet-dapp, cryptography

I want to know if is it possible to hack an Ethereum account?

Comment: It depends what you mean.  It's [computationally infeasible](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10055/is-each-ethereum-address-shared-by-theoretically-2-96-private-keys/10272#10272) and on the practical side you need to [avoid making things insecure](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/how-to-reduce-the-chances-of-your-ethereum-wallet-getting-hacked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible to hack your Ethereum account if the hacker stole your private key, or via phishing if you use an online wallet.Otherwise, it is impossible.