# geth 1.3.6 consistently drops synchronisation after ~5 minutes

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, bug

My geth consistenly stops synchronising after approximately 5-10 minutes of healthy downloading blocks. I've google around and tried various fixes including:

- Running with the flags: `--rpc`, `--cache=512` as mentioned in:
  [Geth stopped syncing after a while](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/geth-stopped-syncing-after-a-while)
- Installing the latest mist wallet and synchronising with that but synchronisation also hangs after about 5 minutes

I ran using the flag `--vmodule=downloader=6` as suggested [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2306) and the output always converges to something like:

`I0601 17:17:38.609524    3531 downloader.go:240] Unregistering peer 2af85be2f92b1abe
I0601 17:17:38.658460    3531 downloader.go:931] Peer 038325873b9be31b [blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: head header timeout
I0601 17:17:38.658514    3531 downloader.go:339] Synchronisation terminated after 3.001480912s
I0601 17:17:38.658529    3531 downloader.go:263] Removing peer 038325873b9be31b: timeout
I0601 17:17:38.658543    3531 downloader.go:240] Unregistering peer 038325873b9be31b
I0601 17:17:38.723505    3531 downloader.go:252] Attempting synchronisation: 55836d952b9d4432, head [f427565c…], TD 23853227086448968682
I0601 17:17:38.723629    3531 downloader.go:337] Synchronising with the network using: 55836d952b9d4432 [eth/63]
I0601 17:17:38.723662    3531 downloader.go:905] Peer 55836d952b9d4432 [blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: retrieving remote chain height
I0601 17:17:38.747023    3531 downloader.go:228] Registering peer 3527031fc9945b8a
I0601 17:17:38.905869    3531 downloader.go:240] Unregistering peer be55471dfeaddea0
I0601 17:17:40.509484    3531 downloader.go:240] Unregistering peer a7f8f52fa4b64dfa
I0601 17:17:41.227673    3531 downloader.go:252] Attempting synchronisation: 55836d952b9d4432, head [f427565c…], TD 23853227086448968682
I0601 17:17:41.227723    3531 downloader.go:260] Synchronisation already in progress
I0601 17:17:41.252802    3531 downloader.go:228] Registering peer 172d5f6904a60131
I0601 17:17:41.725586    3531 downloader.go:931] Peer 55836d952b9d4432 [blocks 0.00/s, receipts 0.00/s, states 0.00/s, lacking    0]: head header timeout
I0601 17:17:41.725675    3531 downloader.go:339] Synchronisation terminated after 3.002020145s
I0601 17:17:41.725689    3531 downloader.go:263] Removing peer 55836d952b9d4432: timeout
I0601 17:17:41.725701    3531 downloader.go:240] Unregistering peer 55836d952b9d4432
I0601 17:17:41.994328    3531 downloader.go:240] Unregistering peer f42cd23b442bed31`

Cancelling (using ctrl-c) and restarting causes geth to sync from the last downloaded block without any issues (but I don't want to have to continuously do this, I'm about 100000 blocks behind -.-).

Any help greatly appreciated!

P.s. I'm willing to remove my entire db and resync using `--fast` but I thought I'd check if there was anything else I could do first.

Comment: any reason why you don't try the latest release ? https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases

Comment: I ran into issues trying to update with brew but I've downloaded the binary you linked and I'm trying it now, thanks :)

Comment: Is it working for you now with the latest release?

Comment: Yep updating geth via the link euri10 posted fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

It's an open bug. [Follow it here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2621).

Workaround:

> sync on a fast system, and copy chaindata to slow system. If error occurs during the (short) sync after the transfer, then just wait, eventually a reply will come during a break in I/O workload, and the sync will make progress. Once synced, the node generates neglibily little I/O work, so it runs smoothly on a system with severly slow I/O (like an ARM board with USB2.0 flash drive).